# knockout JS inner and outer bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to include an inner element in an outer element using knockout, is this in any way possible?

HTML:

```
<div id='id1'>
    <span data-bind="text: outerText()"></span>
    <div id='id2'>
        <span data-bind="text: innerText()"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var outerModel = function() {
    this.outerText = ko.observable("Outer Model - Outer Text");
};
ko.applyBindings(new outerModel(), document.getElementById('id1'));

var innerModel = function() {
    this.innerText = ko.observable("Inner Model - Inner Text");
};
ko.applyBindings(new innerModel(), document.getElementById('id2'));
```

This gives me an error:

```
ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function(){return innerText() }"
Message: 'innerText' is undefined
```

I understand the error as the outer model doesn't contain the innertext and therefore the thing crashes.

My questions is if there is a proper/better/correct way of having an inner element and getting it to work in knockout.

Note: I do not want the innerModel to be a member/child of the outerModel as they are just in this HTML layout for layout purposes but aren't necessarily related.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Usually your best bet there is to make the inner stuff a property of your outer stuff and then just bind normally (possibly with `with`). E.g.:

   ```
   var innerModel = function() {
       this.innerText = ko.observable("Inner Model - Inner Text");
   };
   var outerModel = function() {
       this.outerText = ko.observable("Outer Model - Outer Text");
       this.inner = ko.observable(new innerModel());
   };
   ko.applyBindings(new outerModel(), document.getElementById('id1'));
   ```

   ...and then:

   ```
   <div id='id1'>
       <span data-bind="text: outerText()"></span>
       <div id='id2' data-bind="with: inner">
           <span data-bind="text: innerText()"></span>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

   Example:

   ```js
       var innerModel = function() {
           this.innerText = ko.observable("Inner Model - Inner Text");
       };
       var outerModel = function() {
           this.outerText = ko.observable("Outer Model - Outer Text");
           this.inner = ko.observable(new innerModel());
       };
       ko.applyBindings(new outerModel(), document.getElementById('id1'));
   ```

   ```html
       <div id='id1'>
           <span data-bind="text: outerText()"></span>
           <div id='id2' data-bind="with: inner">
               <span data-bind="text: innerText()"></span>
           </div>
       </div>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
   ```
2. But in cases where that's not possible, you can add a new binding to KO that says "don't bind within this element" as [described here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html):

   ```
   ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
       init: function () {
           return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
       }
   };
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   <div id='id1'>
       <span data-bind="text: outerText()"></span>
       <div data-bind="stopBinding: true">
           <div id='id2'>
               <span data-bind="text: innerText()"></span>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

   ...and then do the two `applyBindings` in your question. (Note that I added a `div` around your `id2` `div`. If you want to use a "virtual element" instead, add this line after the binding handler:

   ```
   ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.stopBinding = true;
   ```

   ...to enable using it with virtual elements.)

   Example:

   ```js
       // Somewhere where you'll only do it once
       ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
           init: function () {
               return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
           }
       };

       // Then:
       var outerModel = function() {
           this.outerText = ko.observable("Outer Model - Outer Text");
       };
       var innerModel = function() {
           this.innerText = ko.observable("Inner Model - Inner Text");
       };
       ko.applyBindings(new outerModel(), document.getElementById('id1'));
       ko.applyBindings(new innerModel(), document.getElementById('id2'));
   ```

   ```html
       <div id='id1'>
           <span data-bind="text: outerText()"></span>
           <div data-bind="stopBinding: true">
               <div id='id2'>
                   <span data-bind="text: innerText()"></span>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
   ```